# XCode 4.5 UiScrollView issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm trying to implement an UIScrollView with Page Control with an array of images. I used same piece of code of another project, but it doesn't work with Xcode 4.5. ScrollView frame properties are all 0 while debugging, but the scrollview Outlet is well connected. Images doesn't show in the scroll. It is really strange. I have observed that properties are not synthesized automatically like previous versions. Here is the code:

```
@interface dashboardViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{

    BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

- (IBAction)changePage;

@end




   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fondo.jpg"]]];

        pageControlBeingUsed=NO;

        scrollView.delegate=self;

        [self buildScrollView];



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    -(void)buildScrollView{

        NSArray *imagesQueue = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icoblog.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"icogaleria.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"icobio.png"], nil];

        for(int i = 0; i < imagesQueue.count; ++i) {

            UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imagesQueue objectAtIndex:i]];

            CGFloat xOrigin = i * (scrollView.frame.size.width);

            image.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);

            [scrollView addSubview:image];

            image=nil;


        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imagesQueue.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);



}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Same for me. I think that something has changed with iboutlet-ed scrollviews and Xcode 4.5. It works when i declare my scrollviews manually

Comment: @theomen, will you please select the answer to your question.

Answer (score 8):

Select your scrollview in the storyboard and untick the "auto layout" under file properties

Comment: THANKS YOU ! I was banging my head for hours searching why my scrollview didn't react to my contentSize ! That "auto layout" new functions is horrible (plenty of bugs with it).

Comment: Wow, I spent hours troubleshooting horrible zoom behavior until I found this... now it just works.

Answer (score 1):

Try pushing "self." infront of all the "scrollView" you don't have it.

Comment: It doesn't works, scrollview still doesn't show : <UIScrollView: 0x71a1c60; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71a2aa0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a1e80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>. Thanks.

Comment: Did you start the project new after you updated to xCode 4.5 or was it an existing project before you updated?